# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

```
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\\database.mdb");
conn.Open();

com = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into group
                          (groupid,groupname,nature,effect) 
                         values 
                          (@groupid,@groupname,@nature,@effect)", conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupid", intialtxt);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupname", groupnametxt);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nature", groupnaturecombo);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@effect", efectivegroupcombo);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close()
```

i have write this connection ,but i get one error Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
please someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess, but try to type [group] instead of just group. I assume the group word is reserved because of the "GROUP BY" clause.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh MS Access with your exceedingly stupid naming allowances, from allowing spaces in table names to permitting use of SQL keywords for field names.

GROUP is a [SQL reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(SQL.80).aspx).  If you have the chance, I highly recommend you rename it.  That said, if you can't rename it, surround it with square brackets in the query [group].

Answer (score 0):

> OleDbCommand(@"insert into group(

You have some typos:

- there should be a space between the table name and your open paren, like this : `group (groupid`
- .

Comment: The @ before a string is fine. It allows mulitline string in C# and you don't need to escape spacial characters. Extremly handy for regex and sql queries. i.e.: string pattern = @"\d+"; instead of string pattern = "\\d+";

Comment: "@" is actually valid where it is; it instructs the string to ignore  escape codes.  For example, it lets you put "\" in a string instead of forcing you to use the escape code of "\\".